# Is there a maximum amount of ADA I can send in one transaction?

Tags: ada, transaction

This question is related to one of my previous questions: [Is there a minimum amount of ADA I can send in a transaction?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/507/1142)

I wonder, if there is a minimum amount of ADA I can send in one transaction, is there a maximum amount too? Or would it theoretically be possible to send all 45B ADA in one transaction (if someone would own all ADA there is)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit amount of output ADA is specified as `Word64` which is an 64-bit unsigned integer, therefore the maximum output is `18 446 744 073 709 551 615` lovelaces in the current implementation.

So, sending all 45 billion of ADA is theoretically possible.

Comment: Where did you see `Word64`? I don't think there is a direct artificial limit. See the definition of `TxOut` and `Value`. `Value` uses `Integer`, which has no limit. https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/tutorial/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Tx.html#t:TxOut https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/tutorial/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Value.html#t:Value