# Is it possible to send a native token to another wallet while sending the minimum amount of ADA to my own wallet?

Tags: transaction, native-assets, utxo

Every transaction needs to include at least 1 ADA (See: [Is there a minimum amount of ADA I can send in a transaction?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/507/1142)).

I want to send a native token to someone else, but I don't want to send them the 1 ADA.

Let's say we have the following wallets (TokenX is a native token or NFT):

- WalletA:

  - UTxO: 2 ADA
  - UTxO: 1 TokenX
- Wallet B:

  - UTxO: 10 ADA

WalletA wants to send 1 TokenX to WalletB. Can I construct a transaction where I send 1 TokenX to WalletB and 1 ADA to my own WalletA address?

The end result would look like this (ignoring transaction fees for simplicity):

- WalletA:

  - UTxO: 2 ADA
- Wallet B:

  - UTxO: 10 ADA
  - UTxO: 1 TokenX

How can this be done and is this possible in Yoroi or Daedalus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Every transaction needs to include at least 1 ADA (See: Is there a minimum amount of ADA I can send in a transaction?).

No, every UTxO (i.e. output you're sending asset to) needs to be atleast 1 ADA. This was included to prevent dust and spamming on blockchain. In future , it will be possible to offload this minUtxo fee to block creators who may opt-in to this feature.
You can read more about it [here](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/02/25/babel-fees/). There will be updates to protocol parameters as part of Alonzo, but this will likely not change in immediate future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This kind of sucks as it makes small payments (e.g. tips) using native assets (as well as ADA) pretty much impossible since you always have to pay 1 ADA (currently >$1) extra plus the fees.

Comment: With babel (link in the reply) , you dont pay for any minimum output, as it will be offloaded to block producers. The idea is to reduce dust transactions on chain, you would still be able to use scripts for alternate fee models, once plutus is fully live.

Answer (score 5):

Emmanuel is correct, based on the coin name there is an amount of ADA that needs to be sent to every target address.
My native token requires 1.444443 ADA to be sent to each and every target address, i.e. if I want to send 1 Bingo Token to 100 individual addresses, I have to send 1.444443 ADA to each target address, irrespective of whether I batch them all into one transaction.
Really hope this falls away sooner rather than later.

> "based on the coin name" - this statement looks like it is incorrect - see comments below.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the token name influences the amount of ADA needed to send the token?

Comment: @eddex, I saw in a thread in discord that it has to do with the length of your native token name and the amount of decimals, but can't vouch for the accuracy. Actually, after looking into it, I found another example of a 1.44443 minimum ada on a token with 4 letters while I have the same minimum with 5 letters.
Here is a reddit thread discussing the fee: https://www.reddit.com/r/ADAXPRO/comments/o6cnle/moving_adax_to_yoroi_wallet/

Answer (score 3):

Every Native Asset is sort of conjoined to 1.4XXXXXX ADA from my experience and so it basically impossible to simply just send the native asset by itself. It’s a part of it. You’ll end up having to cover transaction fees with part of your 2 ADA.

This is all from my time manually minting and sending assets with the CLI. Will advise further research.

Comment: What do you mean by "conjoined to 1.4 ADA"? To my understanding native assets are completely independent assets that live next to ADA. You only need ADA to pay for transaction fees and to cover the minimum amount that needs to be sent in a transaction.

Comment: Every native asset UTXO must move with at least 1ADA. It’s called the min-ada-value. With time and parameter adjustments that value will change.